# Urls with ".html" suffix in FlatPages

Tags: python, django, django-flatpages

I FlatPages to display pages with .html suffix. When I try to create page with url like `/about/policy.html` I get error `URL is missing a trailing slash`. So, how can I make FlatPages use any url suffix I want?

Now I have FlatPages middleware in my MiddleWare classes installed:

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    ...,
    'django.contrib.flatpages.middleware.FlatpageFallbackMiddleware',
)
```

, so I don't have any url patterns related to flatpages in my `urls.py`.

Comment: would it be ok to give explicit urls in urls.py for them?

Comment: you should take a look at this http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/format-suffixes.

Comment: You could write a url pattern to match <page>.html then redirect to /<page>/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just removed FlatPages middleware from settings and added this line to the end of my urlpatterns:

```
url(r'^(?P<url>.*)', 'django.contrib.flatpages.views.flatpage'),
```

Answer (score 1):

I think, it is only possible with explicit urls in urls.py

try this.

```
urlpatterns += patterns('django.contrib.flatpages.views',
      url(r'^about/policy.html$', 'flatpage', {'url': '/about/policy.html'}, name='policy'),
)
```

Comment: It's bad if it's really the only solution, because I want users to create pages in admin.